# How to get pair value from CultureTypes object in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, cultureinfo

I have created single object of IEnumerable
want to make it dictionary type object to handle key and value.

want to extract Currency Symbol and Name from the Cultures.

```
 IEnumerable<string> currencySymbols = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures) //Only specific cultures contain region information
            .Select(x => (new RegionInfo(x.LCID)).ISOCurrencySymbol )
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(x => x);
            foreach(string s in currencySymbols)
            {
                CurrencyTable tbl = new CurrencyTable();
                tbl.Iso = s;
                tbl.Name = s;
            }
```

I want like below

```
IEnumerable<string,string>
```

How it possible?
**CurrencyTable** is a class that contains `ID | Iso | Name` Filed

Comment: A thing like `IEnumerable<string,string>` does not exist in C#. What are you trying to achieve? Do you want a ´Dictionary<string,string>` for access by name?

Comment: I want to get all iso & currency name to store in database..

Comment: see the first answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109121/data-member-validation-iso-4217-currency-and-639-1-language want to get iso with name and want to store in database.

Answer (score 3):

this one returns all currencySymbols with its first distinct english currency name

```
var currencySymbols =
        CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures) //Only specific cultures contain region information
       .Select(x => new RegionInfo(x.LCID))
       .GroupBy(x => x.ISOCurrencySymbol)
       .Select(x => new CurrencyTable() {
            Iso = x.Key,
            Name = x.Select(y => y.CurrencyEnglishName).Distinct().FirstOrDefault()
        });
```

and here goes the LINQ-Version:

```
var symbols = from x in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
                  let region = new RegionInfo(x.LCID)
                  group region by region.ISOCurrencySymbol into g
                  let names = from r in g select r.CurrencyEnglishName
                  select new CurrencyTable() {
                      Iso = g.Key,
                      Name = names.FirstOrDefault()
                  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't return `IEnumerable<string,string>`. But you can return `IEnumerable<anonymous tyep>`.

For example :

```
 var currencyTables = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
            .Select(s => new RegionInfo(s.LCID))
            .Select(r => new
            {
                Iso = r.ISOCurrencySymbol,
                Name = r.CurrencyEnglishName
            }).GroupBy(s => s.Iso)
            .OrderBy(r =>r.Key)
            .Select(a => new { Iso = a.Key, Name = a.First().Name });
```

And you can return `IEnumerable<CurrencyTable>`. 
For example:

```
    var currencyTables = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
        .Select(s => new RegionInfo(s.LCID))
        .Select(r => new
        {
            Iso = r.ISOCurrencySymbol,
            Name = r.CurrencyEnglishName
        }).GroupBy(s => s.Iso)
        .OrderBy(r =>r.Key)
        .Select(a => new CurrencyTable{ Iso = a.Key, Name = a.FirstOrDefault().Name });
```